# Django with PostgreSQL database not connecting

Tags: django, postgresql, settings

Just installed PostgreSQL database service, want to use it for my Django project, only for localhost. Also installed pgAdmin3LTS, which is like GUI for PostgreSQL.

PostgreSQL was installed on my os C: PostgreSQL.
With pgAdmin I created a new database name: porfoliodb

Right now my object browser in pgAdmin look like this:

Server groups

-Server (1)

-Djangoserver (locohost:5432)

-Databases (2)

-Porfoliodb

-PostgreSQL

In my settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'portfoliodb'),
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
```

I am new to databases, why does it not connect together?

Comment: Why is there a closing bracket after `NAME`?

Comment: @stackken remove the braket here `'NAME': 'portfoliodb'),` . did you install `psycopg2`? see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes